# How do I make sure a promise has been returned before responding to an incoming request (Swagger/Express)

Tags: node.js, express, request, synchronization

I'm trying to write a simple Swagger API that will allow me to sync a couple of systems on demand. The syncing is one way, so basically the end goal will be to send a request to both system, see what's new/changed/removed on the origin, then update the destination. I've been trying to do this using node.js instead of Java, to which I'm more used to, as a learning experience, but I'm really having a hard time figuring out a key issue due to the async nature.

As a test, I constructed a simple Express node.js app on IntelliJ, where in one of the routes I'm calling a function exported from a different file and trying to get the response back. Unfortunately, this isn't working so well. What I've done is this:

getit.js - (this goes to the Ron Swanson generator to get a quote)

```js
const rp = require('request-promise');

async function dorequest() {

    const response = await rp(uri);
    return Promise.resolve(response);
};

module.exports = {dorequest}
```

In the route I've done this:

```js
var getit = require ('./getit.js');
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var ret = getit.dorequest();
    res.send(ret);
    console.log('res out' + ret);
});
```

What I get in the console is

> res out[object Promise]
>   and the response is of course empty.

What am I doing wrong? I've been playing with this for a week now, tried various methods, but I keep getting similar results. I'm obviously missing something out, and would appreciate some help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object is empty because it was written on the console before the Promise is resolved. You have to wait until Promise is resolved and then send the response back so try to change your code like this:

```
var getit = require ('./getit.js');

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    getit.dorequest().then(function(data) {
        console.log('res out' + data);
        res.send(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `async/await` approach all you need to do is to place `await` before `getit.dorequest();`

so this line will look like `var ret = await getit.dorequest();`